# Trigger method when image is loaded (Internet Explorer)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to trigger a method when the image is loaded. Unfortunately, `.load` doesn't work for images in the Internet Explorer. Is there some kind of workaround?

Here is my code:

```
<img
  ref="image"
  :src="src"
  :alt="alt"
  @load="onLoad"
/>
```

script:

```
methods: {
  onLoad() {
    console.log('trigger me when image has fully loaded');
  },
}
```

Comment: The native `load` method works for images well in IE, maybe this is some Vue stuff ..?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact that IE loads the image even when an image element isn't attached yet to the DOM but defined as an unattached `img` element. As soon as the `src` attribute is set the loading starts.
The hook is most likely bound **after** the element is attached tot he DOM, which causes it to miss the actual `onload` event and hence it will never be triggered.

A solution could be to hardcode an onload handler in it for Internet Explorer.

```
<img onload="
          var event = new Event('imageloaded',{
                                          currentTarget: this
                                 });
          document.body.dispatchEvent(event);">
```

This will then trigger an event on the body element that the image is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly on IE as well

```
<img id="img" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" />
<script>
    function myFunction(){
        console.log('image loaded')
    }

    document.getElementById('img').addEventListener('load', myFunction)
</script>
```